# How to support Entity Framework when using State pattern and avoid data bloat?

Tags: .net, design-patterns, entity-framework-core, orm

I want to implement a state machine for `Entity`, I followed State design pattern: https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/state/csharp/example . The issue is that I don't know how to properly support EF Core in this scenario to avoid data redundancy.

Issues:

1. I cannot generate migration because `State` is abstract. Should I just remove `abstract`?
2. `abstract State` needs primary key
3. How to avoid `State` table bloating? In case I just would use switch based logic and enums I would just have few entries in the `State` table.

---

```
public class Entity
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public State State { get; private set; }
}

public abstract class State
{
    protected Entity _entity;

    public State(Entity conformanceRegister)
    {
        _entity = entity;
    }

    public abstract void Action1();
    public abstract void Action2();
    public abstract void Action3();
    public abstract void Action4();
}

public class ConcreteState1 : State
{
    public ConcreteState1 (Entity entity)
    {
        _entity = entity;
    }

    public override void Action1()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void Action4()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void Action3()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void Action2()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class ConcreteState2 : State
{
    public ConcreteState2 (Entity entity)
    {
        _entity = entity;
    }

    public override void Action1()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void Action4()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void Action3()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void Action2()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class ConcreteState3 : State
{
    public ConcreteState3 (Entity entity)
    {
        _entity = entity;
    }

    public override void Action1()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void Action4()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void Action3()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void Action2()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should not store the State in the database. You only save the Entity with current status. When you get it from EF, set the correct State for the entity from the entity's status